# Forming an expression with vector in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create an expression of the from `val %in% c(3,4)` to pass in to a query in data.table, where `c(3,4)` is a dynamic vector.

I tried:

```
var = "val"
value = c(3,4)
s = substitute(x := ifelse(x %in% y, 1, 0), 
                           list(x = as.symbol(eval(var)), 
                                y = as.symbol(eval(value))))
```

but the result is:

```
`:=`(val, ifelse(val %in$% `3`, 1, 0))
```

i.e. only the first element of the vector shows up.

what would be a more elegant of doing this without going the `as.symbol(paste())` way. bquote doesn't work either.

***Edit**:*

I realized that any dynamic vector can be passed by name to the query expression in data.table. i.e. `val %in% value` works. So my problem is solved, but I would still like to to know if there is a way to generate the above *expression*.

Comment: Sorry. typo. fixed it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, but you might want to try building an expression in this way: `\`:=\`(x=ifelse(...,...,...))` so that you can pass it in `DT[,eval(myexpr)]` (which I assume is what you mean to do, but do not see you explicitly mentioning anywhere).

Comment: x = c(3,4)
I want to create a function(x) whose output is the "expression" `val %in% c(3,4)` (i.e. it looks exactly like this).

Comment: I'm not a `substitute` wizard, but this seems to solve that problem: `myfun <- function(x) substitute(expression(val %in% x)); myexpr <- myfun(c(3,4));eval(eval(myexpr))`. :) I'm not clear on how you brought up `data.table`. I see the `:=` symbol, but don't know where it came from. I think the syntax is roughly `\`:=\`(varname,value)`, so the way you're using "val" there might not work...but I'm just guessing at why := is there.